# Insert document into mongodb from existing table

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to write a query in mongo that will create a new table, loop through my data set, and insert the TopExecutiveTitle into the new table. I also would like it to keep count of each position and only insert a position into the table when it is new.

This is what I have so far. This code loops through my table and inserts the TopExectuiveTitle into a new table. However, it does not group them together and keep count. How do I write my query so that it will?

```
db.car.find().forEach( function (x) {
db.TopExecutiveTable.insert({Topexecutivetitle: x.Topexecutivetitle}) 
});
```

Here is a sample of a document in my database.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a22c8e562c2e489c5df70fa"),
    "2016rank" : 1,
    "Dealershipgroupname" : "AutoNation Inc.?",
    "Address" : "200 S.W. 1st Ave.",
    "City/State/Zip" : "Fort Lauderdale, FL 33301",
    "Phone" : "(954) 769-7000",
    "Companywebsite" : "www.autonation.com",
    "Topexecutive" : "Mike Jackson",
    "Topexecutivetitle" : "chairman & CEO",
    "Totalnewretailunits" : "337,622",
    "Totalusedunits" : "225,713",
    "Totalfleetunits" : 3,
    "Totalwholesaleunits" : "82,342",
    "Total_units" : "649,415",
    "Total_number_of _dealerships" : 260,
    "Grouprevenuealldepartments*" : "$21,609,000,000",
    "2015rank" : 1
}
```

The result I would like is something like this

```
"Topexecutivetitle" : "chairman & CEO" 
           "Count"  : 3
"Topexecutivetitle" : "president" 
           "Count"  : 7
}
```

Comment: can you please add sample data set and your expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you need to use the [aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) function of mongo, something like this:

```
db.car.aggregate([
{
    $group:{
            _id:"$Topexecutivetitle",
            count:{$sum:1}
        }
},
{
    $project:{
            Topexecutivetitle:"$_id",
            count:1,
            _id:0
        }
 },
 {
     $out:"result"
 }])
```

This will give you your desired output and store it into a new collection "result":

```
{
    "_id" : "president",
    "count" : 1.0
},
{
    "_id" : "chairman & CEO",
    "count" : 3.0
}
```

Comment: It supposed to take the Topexecutivetitle field and insert it into a new table and do a group by and keep count.

Comment: I didn't get your question? do you mean It should first take Topexecutivetitle to a new collection and then take a count? What's wrong if you do group by at first step?

Comment: No, then you need 2 queries, one to create a new collection and the second one to know the count.